# how to test the execution speed of code in android?

Tags: android, testing, benchmarking

I want to test my code execution speed,
my code :

```
public static String foo () {

         final long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis ();
         try {
             // my code here
             long final endtime = System.currentTimeMillis ();
             System.out.println ("Total execution time:" + (endtime - startTime));
             return msg;
         } Catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
             return "ERROR";
         }
     }
```

but after execute this code multiple times (repeat test), I find the difference between total execution of same code. I assume it is because the systems loaded with background process. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: How long does your code take to run? If it completes quickly (less than a second) you'll want to run it multiple times and divide by the number of runs. Also, prefer `System.nanoTime()` over `System.currentTimeMillis()` as the former uses the monotonic clock.

Comment: @fadden yes it run under 1 sec, so there is no way to get the real code execution time without systems loaded process affecting it? also, thank you for nanotime suggestion :)

Comment: It may not have anything to do with background processes. Mobile devices run at low power when idle, and don't ratchet up the clocks until there's a load for a certain amount of time. If your code runs entirely in the ramp-up period it will not finish as quickly as it would if the CPU were running at full speed. On the other side, clocks can be slowed due to thermal throttling. And if you're running in an AsyncTask, the thread itself runs at a lower priority. Benchmarking is hard. :-) Find a way to execute the same code 100x, then divide the time by 100.

Answer (score 1):

As you said, you need to run this over several tries and take an average. That would be the most accurate way. This value could vary across devices, and be vastly different on the same device depending on the applications running in the background.

Android recommends using the `TimingLogger` class. 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/TimingLogger.html